# SQLAlchemy Group By With Full Child Objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Imagine the following Media table:

```
| site       | show_id | time |
| ---------------------|-------|
| CNN        | 1       | 'a'   |
| ABC        | 2       | 'b'   |
| ABC        | 5       | 'c'   |
| CNN        | 3       | 'd'   |
| NBC        | 4       | 'e'   |
| NBC        | 5       | 'f'   |
--------------------------------
```

I would like to iterate over query results grouped by show_id and have tried this query:

```
listings = session.query(Media).filter(Media.site == "CNN").group_by(Media.show_id).all()
```

Here's how I would like to iterate over the results:

```
for showtimes in listings:
    for show in showtimes:
        print(show.time)
```

But that query doesn't give me all of the grouped child objects.  What am I missing?

Comment: what objects did you get? and what all are missing? Add your expected output and actual output you are getting.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `group by` does. Group by is typically used for aggregations. So for example, you would run `select site, count(*) from media group by site`, which would result in *one* row for each site, along with how many rows have that site.

But what you're asking for isn't an aggregation.

Comment: I assumed there was some sort of subquery of group_by that was needed to get the related objects.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In SQL the GROUP BY clause *condenses the grouped rows into a single row*, based on the grouping expressions. My guess is that you are using SQLite, or an older version of MySQL, since you are allowed to select non-aggregates without them being [functionally dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) on the grouping expressions. The results contain values from an unspecified row per group in that case, which is seldom — if ever — useful.

A solution is to ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY in SQL and then [group in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based on the order expressions:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

listings = session.query(Media).\
    filter(Media.site == "CNN").\
    order_by(Media.show_id).\
    all()

# Materialize the subiterators to lists
listings = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(listings, attrgetter('show_id'))]
```

Comment: While this is a solution, its not exactly a database solution. Is this impossible to do purely in sql alchemy so it happens completely in the db?

Comment: It's not entirely impossible. For example if your DBMS supports JSON and has a JSON list aggregation function, you could build a JSON list of objects all within the DBMS. In other words, you'd condense the grouped rows into a single row, with a column of JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

listings = session.query(Media).\
    filter(Media.site == "CNN").\
    order_by(Media.show_id).\
    all()

# Materialize the subiterators to lists
key_listings = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(listings, attrgetter('show_id'))}
```

This way can convert to dict as usefully.