# In Flask how do I query my database using SQLAlchemy so that I filter for multiple things?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an app in flask that is meant to be reporting the retention rates of staff members. I am wanting to break up the results by company and by whether they are currently employed or not and I want to order by their retention rates.

I am wanting to replicate the below sql query in sql alchemy but I am having troubles.

Here is basically the sql query that I want to create in sql alchemy:

```
select * from staffmembers where currentEmployee=1 group by company order by retention desc;
```

And here is my flask model:

```
class StaffMember(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'staffMembers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    position = db.Column(db.Text)
    company = db.Column(db.Text)
    startDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    endDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    retention = db.Column(db.Integer)
    currentEmployee = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

My current sqlalchemy query is:

```
staff = StaffMember.query.filter_by(user=current_user).group_by(company).order_by(StaffMember.retention.desc()).all()
```

The problem is that my reports page is only showing one person per company rather than all of the people in that company with those particular data.

My html code is:

```
{% for person in staff %} 
    <div class="myform-outercontainer">
        <div  style="width: 650px;">
                <div style="height: 20px"></div>
                        <h3>Current Staff Members:</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 50px" class="my-center">ID</th>
                <th class="my-center">Name</th>
                <th class="my-center">Position</th>
                <th class="my-center">Company</th>
                <th class="my-center" style="width: 100px">Start Date</th>
                <th class="my-center" style="width: 100px">Retention</th>

            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.id}}</td>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.name}}</td>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.position}}</td>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.company}}</td>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.startDate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}}</td>
                <td class="my-center">{{person.retentionNow()}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Any help would be appreciated! :-D

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY company`? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731361/sqlalchemy-group-by-with-full-child-objects, tl;dr `GROUP BY` condenses grouped rows to a single group row. Perhaps you wanted to `ORDER BY company, retention DESC` instead?

Comment: You are right, GROUP BY does something different to what I had thought. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
staff = StaffMember.query.filter_by(user=current_user).group_by(company).order_by(StaffMember.retention.desc()).all()
```

This query would return all the records which matches the user col value with the current user and in this situation i guess there is only one record per user.

I guess your looking for a query for something like this.

```
staff = StaffMember.query.filter_by(currentEmployee=True).group_by(company).order_by(StaffMember.retention.desc()).all()
```

which gives you all the staff members filtered by currentEmployee and grouped by company and ordered by the desc retention rates.

You almost had it just had to change the filter_by logic.

Comment: That's true, I had stuffed up the filter_by logic. I also think that group by is not what I was really after - as it always summarises the results that are the same... which is not what I wanted. I will try and work out a different way of filtering to get more results. I might see if I can add multiple filter by criteria into the query. Thanks for your help!