# Get row iterables for each group via GROUP BY clause

Tags: python, group-by, sqlalchemy

I know how to get an iterable for all the rows in a selection, but I would like to add a `GROUP BY` statement to my selection and return a set of iterables instead, one for each group. That is, suppose I have a table like so:

[image]

and suppose I want to group by `nationality`; I would like a set (e.g. iterable) of iterables with the following rows: `[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 6], [7]` (in no particular order). Currently I'm doing this manually using `order_by` on `nationality` and iterating over all the rows; is there a built-in way using sqlalchemy?

From what I've read, the `group_by` method only allows you to do what SQL `GROUP BY` does, which is somewhat limited - I'm looking for something like the pandas groupby which allows you to apply an arbitrary function to each group.

Comment: i think it is only possible if you make a custom `group by` AFTER you get the results.  SqlAlchemy group by is a reflection of sql group by which has a different functionality than what you intent here

Comment: I don't think SQLAlchemy offers what you're after, you need to use for example `itertools.groupby`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731361/sqlalchemy-group-by-with-full-child-objects/52773549#52773549

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) is what you were looking for:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'name':['Franz','Louis','Werner','Leonardo','Antoine','Marco','Nacho'],
    'nationality':['Germany', 'France', 'Germany','Italy', 'France','Italy','Spain']
})

# Group
grouped = df.groupby(['nationality'])

# Iterate over Group
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

Output

```
France
   id     name nationality
1   2    Louis      France
4   5  Antoine      France
Germany
   id    name nationality
0   1   Franz     Germany
2   3  Werner     Germany
Italy
   id      name nationality
3   4  Leonardo       Italy
5   6     Marco       Italy
Spain
   id   name nationality
6   7  Nacho       Spain
```